# TypeError: undefined is not a function GET request/db call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I am getting a TypeError when using node.js to execute a GET request. It looks the same as all my other requests in all my other modules. The error is being returned in the code executed between my two created modules, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.exports.getFollowingWatches (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/modules/feed/feeddb.js:23:11)
at /Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/modules/feed/index.js:55:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/M/Desktop/Projects/BX-Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
```

Get request:

```
router.get("/getFollowingWatches", function(req, res, callback) {
    var userId = req.query.userId;
    var position = req.query.pos;

    if ((!(userId >= 1 && userId <= 9223372036854775807)) || (userId == undefined)) { //max signed
        res.status(400).send("userId invalid");
        return;
    }

    if (!(position >= 0 && position <= 100000)) { //what is the optimal max number? should do something elegant when this number is reached
        res.status(400).send("max position number exceeded");
        return;
    }

    db.getFollowingWatches(userId, position, function(feed) {
        if (!feed) {
            res.status(404).send("feed could not be loaded");
        } else {
            res.json(feed);
        }
    });
});
```

db call:

```
exports.getFollowingWatches = function(userId, position, callback) {
    //@TODO: update interval time
    var sql = "SELECT  p.profilename AS watchname, p.idperson AS watchid, b.idbounty, b.description, b.idcreatedfor, b.contenttype " +
        "FROM bounty b " +
        "INNER JOIN watch w ON b.idbounty = w.idbounty " +
        "INNER JOIN person p ON p.idperson = w.idperson " +
        "WHERE w.idperson IN (select beingfollowed from follow where isfollowing = ?) " +
        "AND timewatched >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 100 YEAR " +
        "AND b.iscomplete = 0 " +
        "LIMIT BY ?, ?";
    var inserts = [userId, parseInt(position), 20];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

    console.log("getFollowingWatches db function running... " + sql);
    dbcommon.executestatement(pool, sql, callback); //this line executes but an error is returned before the if statement is hit back in the GET request
};
```

dbcommon.executestatement... is being executed but before the if statement can be executed back in the GET request, the error is hit

Comment: Are you sure it isn't supposed to be `executeStatement()` with a capital `S`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't capitalise the S in dbcommon.executeStatement. This is solved now. Programming, lol.